# EJB3.1 properties file injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

is there some simple way to inject Properties class loaded with a file from the classpath into EJB (3.1)?

Something like this:

```
@Resource(name="filename.properties", loader=some.properties.loader)
private Properties someProperties;
```

Thank you,

Bozo

Comment: Not easily in standard JavaEE.  I suspect CDI can do something like this with @Inject+@Produces, but I'm not familiar enough with CDI.  (Leaving this comment with the hope that someone else can fill in the details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bkail said, you can achieve this in the following way. I am not sure what your `loader=some.properties.loader` really meant, so skipped doing anything with that, but provided option for that in case you want to load using the `loader.getClass().getResourceAsStream ("filename.properties");`

First define your injection type

```
@BindingType
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD,
        ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface PropertiesResource {

    @Nonbinding
    public String name();

    @Nonbinding
    public String loader();

}
```

Then create a producer for that

```
public class PropertiesResourceLoader {

    @Produces
    @PropertiesResource(name = "", loader = "")
    Properties loadProperties(InjectionPoint ip) {
        System.out.println("-- called PropertiesResource loader");
        PropertiesResource annotation = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(
                PropertiesResource.class);
        String fileName = annotation.name();
        String loader = annotation.loader();
        Properties props = null;
        // Load the properties from file
        URL url = null;
        url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(fileName);
        if (url != null) {
            props = new Properties();
            try {
                props.load(url.openStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return props;
    }
}
```

Then inject it into your Named component.

```
@Inject
@PropertiesResource(name = "filename.properties", loader = "")
private Properties props;
```

I did this looking into the weld documentation where the @HttpParam is given as an example [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1113). This is as per weld 1.1.0, in weld 1.0.0, the getting annotation can be done like this

```
PropertiesResource annotation = ip.getAnnotation(PropertiesResource.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the application server you are using has WELD as the CDI implementation (Glassfish 3.x or JBoss 7.x or Weblogic 12 are examples) then you want to use a WELD **extension** which is explained in the WELD documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/extensions/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted)

It is as simple as adding this to your POM

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-extensions</artifactId>
  <version>${weld.extensions.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```